# Get only 1k bytes from HTTP Response

Tags: http, curl, byte, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm currently do PHP Curl connection and I want to retrieve only the first 1k bytes of the Http Response. The server probably not accept Range-Bytes. Do you know some other way?

Comment: Please post your cURL code so we can make a recommendation.

Comment: if the server doesn't support ranges, your ONLY option is to download the ENTIRE response, then use substr() to pull out the 1000 bytes.

Comment: Exist another way to read a HTTP Response and send a timeout to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a socket connection?

```
// set the server and path
$server = 'example.com';
$path = '/';

// create a socket connection to the server
$socket = fsockopen($server, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);

if (!$socket) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    // send the HTTP request
    fwrite($socket, "GET $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fwrite($socket, "Host: $server\r\n");
    fwrite($socket, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

    // read the first 1000 bytes of the response
    $response = '';
    $i = 0;
    while (!feof($socket) && $i < 1000) {
        $response .= fread($socket, 1);
        $i++;
    }

    // close the socket connection
    fclose($socket);

    // output the response
    echo $response;
}
```